# phpunit tests run using PHP7.2 and 7.1 are 3x slower than when run using PHP7.0

Tags: phpunit, php-7, laravel-5.5, php-7.1, php-7.2

If I run my tests using PHP7.2 or PHP7.1 they are about 3x slower than if I run them using PHP7.0. Is there anyway to get to the bottom of why this is happening?

Even when I run the test suites (Feature & Unit) separately I still see the slow down. It's only when I run the tests individually does the speed difference become insignificant.

I'm using Laravel 5.5.20 and Laravel Homestead 7.0.1. I have 47 rather simple tests, some hitting the database, others just simple assertions; so there isn't anything that should take ages.

I installed [johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap](https://github.com/johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap) to see which tests take the longest so I could remove those but there isn't a specific test that takes a long time because if I remove the offending test, the next one will take ages (see below).

```
First Run                Second Run
Test A    0.2 sec        Test A    0.2 sec
Test B.   0.3 sec        Test B.   0.3 sec
Test C    0.1 sec        Test C    0.1 sec
Test D    0.1 sec        Test D    0.1 sec
Test E    9.3 sec        REMOVED Test E
Test F    0.3 sec        Test F    9.3 sec <-- Test F now takes ages
Test G    0.2 sec        Test G    0.2 sec
```

I am also using an in-memory SQLite3 database, with the Laravel `CreatesApplication` and `RefreshDatabase` trait as I want each test to run independently.

I do not have Xdebug installed or running. Is there something known that PHP7.1 and PHP7.2 take a long time to run PHPUnit tests? Is there something else I can install (or even run it with Xdebug) to track down what exactly it is that is causing the issue?

**Setup**

```
Laravel 5.5.20
Laravel Homestead 7.0.1 (Per-project installation)
PHPUnit 6.4.4
Vagrant 2.0.1
Virtualbox 5.2.4
```

**Results**

```
PHP 7.2 PHPUnit 6.4.4
Time: 12.4 seconds, Memory: 162.00MB

PHP 7.1 PHPUnit 6.4.4
Time: 12.19 seconds, Memory: 162.00MB

PHP 7.0 PHPUnit 6.4.4
Time: 4.88 seconds, Memory: 162.00MB
```

Comment: Please run phpunit under `perf record` and then check the output of `perf report` for both cases.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I found Kris Wallsmith [tearDown cleanup code](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/18029585104/faster-phpunit). The tests are running 44% faster but memory increased by 5 times. I hope that info is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as you but with XDebug installed. I found a pretty good hint by a user named Roni on Laracasts (I can't find the link anymore, sorry) which says to run tests with the `-n` flag of the `php` command, like this: `php -n vendor/bin/phpunit`.

According to the documentation at [php.net (command line options)](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) this is for running the command without what php.ini is defining. Which means no includes of extensions.

> -n No php.ini file will be used

So, for me it runs tests in a minute now, not in 15 minutes. The problem is kind of strange, because it began with php 7.2 on my machine but others in my team don't have the issue, despite the fact that xdebug is installed. I wonder what really is behind this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this massively speeds up tests when coverage/xdebug isn't required

Comment: You can also do `php -d xdebug.mode=off ./vendor/bin/phpunit`, which feels cleaner to me